# DrawerNavigator of react navigation call what function on drawer close

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I want to dispatch a action when drawer close.But I don't know I need write what function, can you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to custom navigation actions to know when the `DrawerClose` event fired.Here is a simple example:

```
const MyAppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    //...
});

const defaultGetStateForAction = MyAppDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

MyAppDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {

    if (state && action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'DrawerClose') {
        console.log('DrawerClose');
        //dispatch whatever action you want
    }
    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

To known more about how to custom routers, see [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/673b9d2877d7e84fbfbe2928305ead7e51b04835/docs/api/routers/Routers.md).